# invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am having problems sending compact data from controller to vue component as a props.

Code for Blade file:

```
<div id="hotjob">
    <hotjob-component :projects="'{{ json_encode($Projects) }}'"></hotjob-component>
</div>
```

I also tried with `{!! json_encode($Projects) !!` but it's still not working.

Code for Vue File:

```
props: ['projects'],
created()
{

    console.log('From On created');
    console.log(this.projects);
},
mounted()
{
    console.log(this.projects);
    console.log('Hot Job Mounted yeah');
}
```

This is the error I get:

> invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in

Comment: Post the full error please. json_encode most likely produces json with " which then ends your input.

Comment: i couldn't add the error...doing some validation...let me jsfiddle link

Comment: here the link of jsfiddle...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o8e95rbn/

Comment: Hi, I've formatted your code a bit. However, the error message was truncated. Please [edit] your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try with removing single quotes

```
    <div id="hotjob">
     <hotjob-component :projects="{{ json_encode($Projects) }}"></hotjob-component>
    </div>
```

Like this.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the variable to the props directly :

```
<hotjob-component :projects='{{ $Projects }}'></hotjob-component>
```

this should do it

Comment: ""  my qoute are converted into &quote;    Thats the reason,couldn't fetch the data